# Listing all tables with no geometry using Oracle DB and ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, table, oracle-dbms

I imported all my data (including attribute tables without geometry) to Oracle Database (default db : SYSTEM)

I connected it to QGIS and ArcMap.

I need tables that starts with RDF*. it shows in QGIS but not in ArcMap
[image]

The picture below is screetshot from ArcMap's catalog and as you see it shows only feature classes and random tables that i do not know where they are from

This is from QGIS Browser Panel and it has tables that i need, although it also has tables that I don't know where they come from.

[image]
[image]

I want my ArcMap catalog view as in QGIS's browser panel.
can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: There is no picture attached.

Comment: Also: what do you mean by "system" database ? There is no such thing. If you mean the schema (= user) SYSTEM - then don't. That schema is used for database admin tasks. It must NOT contain any other data. The password of SYSTEM (and SYS) should only be known to your DBA. To store any application data, create your own schema - or rather: ask your DBA to create it for you properly with the necessary rights and quotas.

Comment: I am new to Database stuff, so i might be confused on the terms. I will create a new schema and re-upload my data. I'll let you know what happens later

Comment: Definitely use your own schema. All those tables you see are used by the database to manage itself. As a matter of fact, most of those others schemas you see (ctxsys, sys, sysman ... ) are also "system" schemas. Others (hr, oe, pm ...) contain example data for vertical apps. Note also that most of those schemas are locked (you can't connect to them).